# How to convert text (normal logs) to JSON format?

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, fluentd

I am using **FluentD** to push the system Google cloud VM logs to Stack Driver.

I need to convert my logs from Text format to `JSON` format. I have installed TD-Agent don't know how to manage the log conversion.

```
{
 insertId         :  "6dxt8fglcw0a34"   
 labels           : {…}   
 logName          :  "projects/dh-ceng-sandbox/logs/syslog"   
 receiveTimestamp :  "2017-08-10T09:01:47.659627621Z"   
 resource         : {…}   
 textPayload      :  "Aug 10 09:01:43 logging-ceng-591 systemd: Started The Apache HTTP Server."   
 timestamp        :  "2017-08-10T09:01:43Z"   
}
```

Note: Second Last Line its `TextPaylod`
and need to be in **JSON payload**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stackdriver JSON\_PAYLOAD in logs from normal text\_payload using google-fluentd agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933111/stackdriver-json-payload-in-logs-from-normal-text-payload-using-google-fluentd-a)

Comment: That was my question only thanks for replying